# My finger's skin is peeling off

Tags: grammar

He scratched his finger and his finger's skin was a little peeling off.

> "I scratched my finger. **My finger's skin is peeling off**."

Is the word "peeling off" describe well as the image?

[image: Scratched finger]

Comment: The phrase "The skin on my finger is peeling of" sounds a lot more natural

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you told me it's not a hangnail, I don't think there's any special term for what you're trying to describe.

I would just say ***The dead skin on my finger is peeling.*** Or ***The dead skin on my finger is flaking off.*** It's awkward to say ***My finger's skin is peeling.*** (It's better to say "The skin on my finger" rather than "My finger's skin.") Also, you can just say "peeling" instead of "peeling off." ***Peeling off skin*** can be a graphic and unpleasant image in people's imagination, so just "peeling" is enough for people to understand.

If you've been wondering why nobody has answered your question, it's because people don't like to read about peeling skin, even if it's very appropriate, such as when someone gets a bad sunburn.

Comment: Probably it's because the question title is worded like a title of scary stories.

Comment: Haha, possibly, and kind of a strange graphic.

Comment: I wouldn't add "The dead skin..." to the sentence though, maybe just say "The skin..."

Comment: I could go with that. Again, it's just another attempt to soften the image of "peeling skin."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. The image shows what I would describe as peeling skin, and I have heard many people use this term to describe similar situations.

One problem: most people would say 'the skin on my finger is peeling' or 'my finger is peeling' over 'my finger's skin', because it is a little awkward to give a finger possessive.